# XCode 9.1, tableView in ViewController with UINavigation have top space between navigation bar and tableView on iOS 10.3

Tags: uitableview, ios10, xcode9

Here's how the storyboard set.
View's background color is red.
TableView's background color is blue.
[image]

The final effect:
iOS 11.1's tableView in navigation view controller works fine.

iOS 10.3's tableView in navigation view controller have extra space on top of table view.

It's `contentOffSet` been changed.

[image]

Any ideal what I have missing?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but it's adding 8px all around the tableview on the new iOS

Comment: 8px is default content inset.  you can check that.

Comment: 'self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false'   fix this bug